# File input output the last line of the output file is repeating infinite more times

Tags: c++

So the problem I have is that it copies the last line into the numbers2.txt file infinite number of times. idk y its happening like tat it should stop after realizing moving two bytes over is merely going to result in it reaching the eof marker

Here's the code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include<string>

using namespace std;

string conversion(int);

int conversion2(string);

int main()
{
  string initialnumber;
  fstream sample("numbers.txt", ios::in | ios::out);
  ofstream sample2("numbers2.txt");

  if (sample && sample2) {
    int number2;
    string roman;
    int number;
    char ch;

    //cout << ch;
    while (!sample.eof()) {
      sample.get(ch);

      //cout << "OK" << " ";
      if (ch != '1' && ch != '2' && ch != '3' && ch != '4' && ch != '5' && ch != '6'
          && ch != '7' && ch != '8' && ch != '9') {
        sample.seekg(-1L, ios::cur);
        sample >> roman;
        sample.seekg(2L, ios::cur);
        sample2 << roman << " " << conversion2(roman) << endl;
        //cout << conversion2(roman) << " " << roman;
        //cout << "OK";
        int L = sample.tellp();
        cout << L;

      } else {
        sample.seekg(-1L, ios::cur);
        sample >> number2;
        sample2 << conversion(number2) << " " << number2 << endl;
        sample.seekg(2L, ios::cur);
        //int l = sample2.tellp();
        //cout << l << " ";
        //cout << "OK";
      }
    }

  } else {
    cout << "fail";
  }

  sample.close();
  sample2.close();
}
```

Comment: `!sample.eof()` This is nearly always the wrong way to read a file, in this particular case because the last action you perform on the stream at the end of each loop is a `seek`, the `eofbit` and `failbit` flags are reset and the condition is never met.

Comment: I don't understand though once it processes the entire string or number it should immediately reach the eof though

Comment: `seekg` does not set `eofbit` if it tries to seek past the end, if you really want to loop over your file like this test the stream as follows: `while (sample)` which will test for all errors.

Comment: I used the while(sample) but this time it copies the last line twice

Comment: Check the edit to my answer if you want to break out as soon as the stream fails.

Answer (score 1):

My comments above are incorrect about clearing `failbit` and `eofbit` (only the single parameter overload of `seekg` clears `eofbit`), `seekg` sets `failbit` on error however, not `eofbit`, so your loop condition is never met.

From [istream.unformatted]

```
basic_istream<charT,traits>& seekg(off_type off, ios_base::seekdir dir);
```

> Effects: Behaves as an unformatted input function (as described in 27.7.2.3, paragraph 1), except that it does not count the number of characters extracted and does not affect the value returned by subsequent calls to gcount(). After constructing a sentry object, if fail() != true, executes rdbuf()->pubseekoff(off, dir, ios_base::in). **In case of failure, the function calls setstate(failbit)** (which may throw ios_base::failure).

Change your condition to `while (!sample.fail())` or even better `while (sample)` to test for *any* stream error, or `while(sample.get(ch))` to abort on the first read error.

Comment: I did while(sample) but this time it prints out the last line twice

Comment: @VarunGorantla I answered you in the comments above, check the edit.

Comment: @VarunGorantla `while(sample.get(ch))` Remember to get rid of the `sample.get(ch)` line below the `while` loop if you use this.

Comment: The problem is I want to break out the loop when I don't see a number from 1-9 and if I don't see either I X V L M or D how would I write tat in the while(sample.get(ch))

Comment: I figured it out thank you sooo much I have another program which uses similar logic but ironically it executes if you could understand tat program I would greatly appreciate it

Comment: @VarunGorantla you'll need to post a new question in that case. If my answer solved your problem please accept it, if it didn't then you should probably delete this question or post your own solution (I'll have to delete my answer first).

Comment: But before that I have one last question pertaining to this program how would I rewrite the name of the numbers2.txt file back to numbers1.txt file and delete the numbers1.txt file before doing the renaming.

Comment: You're looking for the [`remove()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/remove) function.