# File input output c++

Tags: c++

In the following block of code I have created a numbers.txt document which has the number 1 written on it shouldn't this program spit the word OK back infinite number of times because it's going past the eof marker

```
while (!sample.eof())
{
        char ch;
        sample.get(ch);
        sample.seekp(-1L, ios::cur);
        sample >> initialnumber;
        sample.seekp(2L, ios::cur);
        cout << "OK";

}
```

Comment: Where do you open `sample`?

Comment: I already opened it in the code above it They are no syntax errors I have opened and closed the file after done

Comment: The streamstate is sticky, it is only cleared on explicit request, which is why this only loops until the first time it reaches EOF. On the other hand, I'm not sure I really understand your question...

Comment: I don't understand though I thought it goes past the eof marker and it should repeat infinite number of times

Comment: @VarunGorantla In C++, syntax errors are often the least of your worries. How you pass in that handle is critical. If you end up invoking a copy instead of a reference you could cause problems.

Comment: But I am not declaring any functions though

Comment: I just opened the file before entering the while loop

Comment: -1, please don't forget about punctuation.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing as an "EOF marker"<sup>1</sup>. EOF is simply a file condition defined by going at or past the end of the file. Whether you seek 1 byte or seek 100000 bytes past the end makes no difference: if your file position pointer is past the end, you are at or beyond the End Of File.

Your code reads a character and then backs up (essentially negating the character read). It then reads an integer and skips two characters past that. This has the effect of always moving forward in the file (even if the integer read fails). Thus, you will eventually hit EOF: there is no infinite loop here.

---

<sup>1</sup> In DOS days, files could contain the 0x1A byte ("ASCII EOF") which would cause certain text readers to stop at that byte. The file contents could physically extend beyond this byte, but text utilities could refuse to read past it. However, the standard C++ libraries treat 0x1A like any other character, and will happily read past it.

Comment: OK that makes sense this is what I initially though but my professor and this other guy on this site completely contradicted everything I have read

Comment: If you mean Ulrich, he is not trying to contradict anything. He's talking about a different issue, and was confused because your question was unclear.

Comment: But I did a different program which follows similar logic and it does the exact opposite thing and this time follows in an infinite loop

Comment: Your different program is **different**. Details matter when coding.

Comment: LoOK at this question please because it contradicts everything you said over here

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25800408/file-input-output-the-last-line-of-the-output-file-is-repeating-infinite-more-ti/25800622?noredirect=1#comment40356928_25800622